# How do I use assert in VHDL correctly?

Tags: vhdl, assert, test-bench

I have in VHDL a code segment which makes me unsure if it's right:
a and b are std_logic_vectors. c1 and c0 are std_logic. Is this correct written? Especially the part "c1 = '1' and c0 = '0'" struggels with me.

```
if unsigned(a) > unsigned(b) then
    assert(c1 = '1' and c0 = '0')
```

Edit: Here is a bigger code segment:

```
    signal a: std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    signal b: std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    signal c1: std_logic;
    signal c0: std_logic;

    begin
    TEST: forBitComperator port map(a, b, c1, c0);
      process
      begin
        for i in 0 to 2**4-1 loop
            for k in 0 to 2**4-1 loop

                wait for 0 ns;

                a <= conv_std_logic_vector(i, 4);
                b <= conv_std_logic_vector(k, 4);

                if i > k then
                  assert c1 = '1' and c0 = '0'
                  report "error ";
               end if;
        end loop;
    end loop;
    wait;
  end process;
end;
```

Comment: The assertion statement lacking either a report or severity clause should be terminated with a semicolon (IEEE Std 1076-2008 10.3 Assertion statement "An assertion statement checks that a specified condition is true and reports an error if it is not."). The assertion statement is otherwise syntactically correct, there's a default error message. A specific question concerning usage semantics could benefit from a [mcve] which also demonstrates object declarations, c1 and c0 are apparently of some character enumerated type. The enclosing if statement (10.8) is not syntactically complete.

Comment: The parentheses are superfluous in the assertion statement snippet. An expression enclosed in parentheses is only valid if it is also valid without the parentheses, the shown expression only contains one logical operator, requiring no parentheses to establish precedence (9.1, 9.2.1).

Comment: You're right thank you.

Comment: I highly recommend that you keep all the `end` statements. Removing them just creates unnecessary confusion.

Comment: Sorry, I added them (I've saw I deleted the wait statement).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parts you were unsure about are correct. `c0`, `c1`, `'0'` and `'1'` are all `std_logic`, so it is correct to compare them in this way. (In VHDL `=` is the equality comparison operator. It doesn't perform an assignment, like in many software programming languages). The result of each comparison is a boolean (`true` or `false`) so can be used with an `assert` statement.

The only part that I think is really wrong is that you must end your `if` with an `end if`. It is usually also recommended that whenever you use `assert`, you `report` an error message and set a `severity` (e.g. `note`, `warning`, `error` or `failure`, depending on how serious the error is). Of course, it must also be terminated with `;`.

Therefore:

```
if unsigned(a) > unsigned(b) then
    assert c1 = '1' and c0 = '0' report "<Error message>" severity warning;
end if;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Oh, you're right, I missed to copy "end if" in my post. 
Hm it's still very strange because the assert generate in my testbench only errors (if I test those cases manually they are correctly).

Comment: Do you mean it reports syntax errors (at compile time) or assertion errors (at run time)? I think it is likely that your code is correct, it is reporting errors correctly, but you don't understand why. You will need to give much more specific details if you want help with that.

Comment: *Hm it's still very strange because the assert generate in my testbench only errors...* The condition  `c1 = '1' and c0 = '0'` would evaluate to FALSE causing the assertion if either c1 /= '1' or c0 /= '0' (DeMorgan's theorem). None of your three questions has provided any clear indication what c1 and c0 represent nor have you demonstrated the original Python code you're trying to produce a VHDL equivalent of unsuccessfully.

Comment: I meant assertion errors. c1 and c0 representing bits: c1=1 and c0=0 for example means a > b. c1=0 and c0=1 a<b and for a = b: c1=c0=0. I added the relevant part of the testbench in the startpost, does it help?

I've a working Python code aswell if it's usefull (I created it only for my own understanding).

Comment: When you check the results manually, how do you do this? Do you just look at the waveform plots in your simulator? Do they look identical? Do you expand delta cycles in the waveform plots? Testing combinational logic can be very confusing if you don't understand the concept of delta cycles. I suspect this may be your problem. One way to check this is to simply register `i`, `k`, `c0` and `c1` (so they're all synchronous) and see if the errors go away. However, we're now getting very far from your original question, which was about VHDL syntax.

Comment: By the way, I found my mistake: I used "wait for 0 ns" but I should used "wait for 1 ns". Everything is working now. Thanks for help.